# Is there a way to access a row column via index and not name it?

Tags: php

The code I have is this

```
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_buildings WHERE player_id = '$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $amounts = array();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $amounts[0] = $row['cursor_amount'];
                    $amounts[1] = $row['grandma_amount'];
                }
```

However what I would like to be able to do is, instead of naming the column like I do here 'cursor_amount' and 'grandma_amount' is do the following:

```
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_buildings WHERE player_id = '$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $amounts = array();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $amounts[0] = $row[0];
                    $amounts[1] = $row[1];
                }
```

Although when I have tried to do this I've received the undefined offset error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and yes I have tried looking for the answer already. I'm not exactly sure of the key terminology I need to make my searches more specific so if the answer for this does already exist I do apologise, feel free to post the link to the correct answer if that is the case instead of explaining it yourself.

Comment: Yes, you can use `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)`

Comment: @AlexJBallz Why do you want to access the columns, which have a name, not by their name? What do you get by using numbers instead?

Comment: @Progman, it allows for me to write a lot less code because now I can assign every variable I need in a loop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the results with a [different function](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

`$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);`